# Track or tracks

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countability

A toy train is stuck on a track because there is no more "track" ahead; We need to add or build more "track" for it to move. Should the word track be plural in this sentence or singular as is correct for its intended meaning?

Comment: Thank you, Mauik and user8399. Since non-countable noun track is acceptable, does it mean that I can introduce the word without "the" anytime such as in this: you need to add "track"?

Comment: whenever you are confused with the articles, use 'some'. That is the trick I play many times! lol... so you need to add some more track! haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!

I'd use 'track' to talk about **the** railway track (if there's only one single/long track) for that particular toy train.

I incline to use 'tracks' (plural) when there are multiple tracks.

**Track:**

[image: track]

**Tracks:**

[image: tracks]

### In the context of a toy train

I'd go for **tracks**. Why? Because you don't have a 'single piece' of track. There are many pieces you need to fix to move the train further.

Here are the 'tracks' you need to fix

[image: toy-train tracks]

Comment: I don't think that explains the whole situation. I would definitely say, "I drove over the tracks," even if I had only crossed one pair of rails.

Comment: hhmm I see but what I said is not utterly incorrect, is it? @user8399. However, there's a railway track near my house. **And**, I'm talking about a single railway track which is actually a pair of tracks.

Comment: I think, the example indicates the length of track instead of number. It's not about number of tracks, it's about longer track for the toy train. If we consider length (like longer track), then also 'track' is correct. Am I wrong in this?

Comment: @RuchirM clarified further in the answer.

Comment: @RuchirM, Your guessing seems more appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: @MaulikV, Thanks for all these visual helps(? Another plural, singular I am confused)

Answer (score 1):

There are few hard-and-fast rules about the singular or plural when it comes to track(s). Maybe that's because there are two rails, or because railway beds often have  two or more sets of tracks, or because *track* existed long before railways did and the word often referred to footprints.

When we have to depart, we can say "I have to make tracks."

Children are warned not to play on  *the railroad tracks*.

A train can be stuck *on the track(s)*.

But:

The railroad *lays track* just as electricians *pull wire* and plumbers *lay pipe* and someone who installs sheetrock for a living might say "Tomorrow we're putting up *wall*".   All in the singular, referring to the thing generically.

Answer (score -1):

> A toy train is stuck on a track because there is no more *track* ahead; We need to add or build more *track* for it to move.

These sentences are correct as written. When we're talking about some length of track on a given route, *track* is a non-count noun. But when we're talking about laying tracks to a new destination- a whole new road- the noun should be *tracks*, plural.